# How can I create a custom view extending from ToggleButton but with the CircleButton style?

Tags: android, togglebutton

I want to create a normal ToggleButton but with the style and effects of this [library](https://github.com/markushi/android-circlebutton)

How can I do that? Maybe creating a custom view that extends from ToggleButton or from CircleButton? Is there any library for styled ToggleButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just extend the CircleButton class given in the library with something like this:

```
public class CustomCircleButton extends CircleButton {
    boolean state = false;

    private int checked = R.drawable.ic_action_check;
    private int unchecked = R.drawable.ic_action_clear;

    public CustomCircleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomCircleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public CustomCircleButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        //Set the default on click to do nothing but toggle
        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Empty
            }
        });
        setImageResource(unchecked); //Set default drawable
    }
    private void toggle() {
        if(state) {
            state = false;
            //Set drawable for true
            setImageResource(checked);
        } else {
            state = true;
            //Set drawable for false
            setImageResource(unchecked);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(final OnClickListener l) {
        super.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                toggle();
                l.onClick(v);
            }
        });
    }
    //Helper methods
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setCheckedIcon(int id) {
        this.checked = id;
    }
    public void setUncheckedIcon(int id) {
        this.unchecked = id;
    }
}
```

Then you all you have to do is define the two states and add it to a view.

```
<com.yourpackage.CustomCircleButton
            android:layout_width="64dip"
            android:layout_height="64dip"
            app:cb_color="#99CC00"
            app:cb_pressedRingWidth="8dip" />
```

Comment: Perfect, it is what I was looking for :)